# Render error in CoordinatorLayout - How can I fix that?

Tags: android, android-layout

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#666666"
>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:title="Screen stream"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
        />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>







<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomsheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
    app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
    app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
    app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="30dp"
    app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="15dp"
    app:menu="@menu/mst"
    tools:ignore="BottomAppBar" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/download"
    android:backgroundTint="#5384D8"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomsheet"
    android:contentDescription="TODO" />




</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Errors**

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

**I tried this two answer but same error**

1.[failed-to-find-attr-textappearancecaption-in-current-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143535/failed-to-find-attr-textappearancecaption-in-current-theme)

2.[an-anchor-may-not-be-changed-after-coordinatorlayout-measurement-begins-before-l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54801002/an-anchor-may-not-be-changed-after-coordinatorlayout-measurement-begins-before-l)

**1. Render error**

```
Failed to find '@attr/textAppearanceHeadline6' in current theme.  
Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

**2. Render error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An anchor may not be changed after CoordinatorLayout measurement begins before layout is complete.
```

**How can I solve this errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with app theme you are using . I tried with app theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`and its working fine(also tried with other app themes like appCompat).